# How would you name a JavaScript getter function that throws an error if not found vs one that returns null?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript, how would you name a getter function that will throw an error if the item is not found vs one that will return null if not found? In Ruby we can do things like `find()` and `find!()`. Anybody have a good way to name these in JS? Best I can think of is `getThing()` and `getThingSafe()`.

Comment: Can't say I've ran into to many situations where I desired a getter to throw an actual error.

Comment: `if(existingObj.hasOwnProperty('getter')){ existingObj.getter }else{ throw new Error('existingObj.getter does not exist'); };`, but you really only want to throw Errors if you are testing.

Comment: When using a type checker like TypeScript or Flow, it's really nice when a function promises never return null.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember most common pattern is to name it as `getThing()` for nullable and `getThingOrThrow()` for throwable methods. For example [ts-morph](https://ts-morph.com) makes it's functions this way